# 2D Char Array For Loop (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am currently working on this problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/encryption.

This is what I have so far

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = in.nextLine();
    double length = input.length();
    int width = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(length));
    int height = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(length));
    char[] letters = input.toCharArray();
    char[][] matrix = new char[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if ((j + i * width) < letters.length) {matrix[i][j] = letters[j + i * width];}
        }
    }
    StringBuffer encrypted = new StringBuffer();

    for (int cols = 0; cols < width; cols++) {  
        for (int rows = 0; rows < height; rows++) {
            encrypted.append(matrix[rows][cols]);
        }
        encrypted.append(' ');
    }
    System.out.println(encrypted.toString());
}
}
```

It fails on the case "feedthedog"-- I print "fto ehg ee" instead of the answer "fto ehg ee dd." Moreover it seems I am never able to get the last iteration of the second for loop in and I can't seem to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I've just run your programm and it seems fine: 'feedthedog' input produces 'fto ehg ee dd' output. I'm using jdk1.7.0_71

Comment: The same correct answer with jdk 1.8.0 update 40. your code seems to work :)

Comment: I'll just add another voice saying the code outputs `fto ehg ee  dd` for me. jav 1.7.0_21

Answer (score 0):

"ensure, height * width >= len(word)"
You're doing that as a check in your loop, which to begin with is inherently bad because height and width are already known. But you are supposed to use it to check width and height, and adjust them if they don't meet the constraint. The exercize is flawed because it doesn't say if width or height should be expanded first.

You are assuming that height is always floor and width is always ciel, while in this case height is one less than it should be, which is why it isnt completing.

Edit: Although floor(sqrt( len(word) )) <= width, height <= ceil(sqrt( len(word) )) might mean that width=...floor, height=...ciel, that statement written as if it were a sort of vector, while they should use a semicolon if that weren't the case. But if so, you simply have your width and height backwards.
And you're using cols < width, rows < height.

Also that isn't really a cipher, as its not reversible.